# How to print a textBlock using conditionals in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to print in a textBlock repeat if a number is less than 80 and paint color red, and more or equal than 80 print successful with green color.

How can I do that in XAML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Converters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx).

Sadly there are no inequality-triggers or the like, so using a converter should do.

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Foreground>
        <Binding Path="TestDouble">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <vc:ThresholdConverter BelowValue="{x:Static Brushes.Red}"
                                       AboveValue="{x:Static Brushes.Green}"
                                       Threshold="80" />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </TextBlock.Foreground>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding Path="TestDouble">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <vc:ThresholdConverter BelowValue="Repeat"
                                       AboveValue="Successful"
                                       Threshold="80" />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

```
public class ThresholdConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public double Threshold { get; set; }

    public object AboveValue { get; set; }
    public object BelowValue { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double input;
        if (value is double)
        {
            input = (double)value;
        }
        else
        {
            var converter = new DoubleConverter();
            input = (double)converter.ConvertFrom(value);
        }
        return input < Threshold ? BelowValue : AboveValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: But using converters, how can I set those values to the properties?

Comment: @oscar.imbres: You need to bind it to the same value as the text. (Above is an example implementation, you can also bind directly to the `Text`, but then the converter would need to parse the input value first), if you do not know how to use data binding, see [the overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

Comment: @oscar.imbres: Edited it to use a generic double converter, now you can also bind it to the text.

Comment: I see, one more question: is it possible to set the text at the same time? I mean at this line:  <vc:ThresholdConverter BelowValue="{x:Static Brushes.Red}"
                        AboveValue="{x:Static Brushes.Green}" Threshold="80" />

Comment: @oscar.imbres: That is just the creation of the converter, it has nothing to do with the text. `Text` and `Foreground` are set independently.

Comment: @oscar.imbres: Just create a new converter like this and set it as text, one second. Edit: Done, see answer.

Comment: Ohh, I really like the two ways to do this. I think I'm gonna implement this one.

Comment: @oscar.imbres: Just watch the kind of input the converter gets, i just noticed that the `DoubleConverter` is quite stupid, if it gets an input which is already a double it does not return it but throw an exception, so you either create some different cases or make sure the converter gets the right input.

Answer (score 2):

```
<local:NumberToBrushConverter x:Key="numberToBrushConverter" />
<local:NumberToTextConverter x:Key="numberToTextConverter" />

<TextBlock Background="{Binding Number, Converter={StaticResource numberToBrushConverter}}"                    
Text="{Binding Number, Converter={StaticResource numberToTextConverter}"/>
```

---

```
class NumberToBrushConverter: IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int number = (int)value;

        return number < 80 ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Green;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The other converter would look similar to the brush converter, but return "Successful" or "Repeat".